# Python3 / Tkinter for loop displaying buttons with images in

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using Python3.8 and Tkinter to create a program. I'm trying to loop through the below loop and print a button with the image from "onecard" as the image in the button. The problem I'm having is only the last card is being printed. This is my loop:

Please note: "spades" is an array of images ie

```
['images/spade/As.png', 'images/spade/Ks.png']
```

```
for onecard in spades:
    img = Image.open(str(onecard))
    img = img.resize((50, 70), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
    btn = tk.Button(window, text="click"+str(startcol), image=photoImg, width=50, height=70, command=lambda onecard=onecard: click(onecard))
    btn.grid(column=startcol, row=0)

    startcol+= 1
    print(onecard)
```

and this is the output:

[image]

I'm prob missing something simple here but for the life of me I can't work it out. Help much appreciated! <3

Comment: can you tell us what the `spades` is being refered to

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll update it, but its an array of image names

Comment: so are you having 13 items in the list spades?

Comment: Yeah thats correct bud

Comment: See similar question [trying-to-put-images-from-a-folder-onto-tkinter-buttons-only-the-last-image-is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696252/trying-to-put-images-from-a-folder-onto-tkinter-buttons-only-the-last-image-is).

Comment: Yeah thanks for that!!