# Can't reuse variable assigned with tkinter.PhotoImage

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I'm trying to loop through a dictionary that contains the names of icons that I want to add to a tkinter Menu object. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
token_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tokens",
                    underline=0,
                    menu=token_menu)
for coin in cbp_symbols.keys():
    imgvar = PhotoImage(file=f"icons/{cbp_symbols[coin]['icon']}")
    token_menu.add_command(label=f"{coin} ({cbp_symbols[coin]['name']})",
                           image=imgvar,
                           compound=LEFT,
                           command=quit)
win.config(menu=menubar)
```

The problem I'm running into is the reuse of the `imgvar` variable. For example, if I run the loop once, the icon gets added. If I remove the loop and add each menu items separately (and change the name of `imgvar` to something like `imgvar1`, `imgvar2`, etc.), the icons get added. However, every time I try this loop it always dies on the second assignment of `imgvar`. I've tried deleting it, setting to null - nothing I've done works.

Now, if I remove the image commands, the menu populates with the names of all 38 coins in my dictionary. I've verified that the loop is picking up the right icon name/location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to put images from a folder onto tkinter buttons. Only the last image is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696252/trying-to-put-images-from-a-folder-onto-tkinter-buttons-only-the-last-image-is)

Comment: I wish it did. When I run my loop as posted, I'm not getting any images or new menu entries - no errors reported, just nothing at all. I'll try to see the logic used in your link.

Comment: In the link it talks about assigning icons to different Button objects. I can't find any documentation on how to edit an individual Menu entry, other than to add a new one.

Comment: The main point of the solution is to save the references of the images.  For your case, use a list to store the images.

Comment: Wow - that actually worked! Thanks a bunch! If you want to add an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Do you really need `imgvar` variable? can you do direct assignment like this: `image = PhotoImage(...),`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you used same variable `imgvar` to hold the references of `PhotoImage` instances, so only the final image has variable reference to it. The other images will then be garbage collected.

For your case, you can use a list to store the references of the images:

```py
imagelist = []
for coin in cbp_symbols.keys():
    imgvar = PhotoImage(file=f"icons/{cbp_symbols[coin]['icon']}")
    token_menu.add_command(label=f"{coin} ({cbp_symbols[coin]['name']})",
                           image=imgvar,
                           compound=LEFT,
                           command=quit)
    imagelist.append(imgvar) # save the reference of image
```